# Angular2 Final: HostBinding not working anymore

Tags: angular

This is how I host-binded to a button attribute named "disabled" on parent component in ng2-RC4:

```
@Component({
    selector: "nav-next",
    template: `
    <div class="nav-next-directive" (click)="onClick($event)">
        <button color="primary" class="primary" [attr.disabled]="disabled">
            <ion-spinner *ngIf="ngIf === true" icon="lines"></ion-spinner>
            {{buttonTitle}}
        </button>
    </div>`
})

export class NavNextDirective {

    @HostBinding("attr.disabled"); 
    @Input() isValid: boolean;
```

This does not work anymore, (ngc complains) I now have gotten half way there by changing above in part to:

```
@HostBinding("attr.disabled") isValid: boolean = true;
@Input() isValid: boolean;
```

Yet ngc says:

```
Can't bind to 'isValid' since it isn't a known property of 'nav-next'.
1. If 'nav-next' is an Angular component and it has 'isValid' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'nav-next' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("
    <ion-list>
        <nav-next (click)="save()"
                  [ERROR ->][isValid]="goalForm.valid"
                  [serverWaiting]="serverWaiting"
                  button"): GoalDefineAmountComponent@30:18
```

Any ideas how Hostbinding works now?

Answer (score 1):

The error has nothing to do with host binding. It's about the `NavNextDirective` not being known to the component trying to use it

The `NavNextDirective` needs be in the same *scope* as the component that is using it. That means you can either declare it in the same module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ NavNextDirective, ComponentThatUsesNavNextDirective ]
})
class SomeModule {}
```

Or if the `NavNextDirective` is to be used by different modules, either declare and export the directive in its own module or in a shared module, and import that module into the modules that have components that use that directive

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ NavNextDirective ],
  exports: [ NavNextModuleDirective ]
})
class NavNextModule {}

// OR

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ NavNextDirective ],
  exports: [ NavNextModuleDirective ]
})
class SharedModule {}
```

Then import it

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ SharedModule ]
  declarations: [ ComponentThatUsesNavNextDirective ]
})
class ModuleWithComponentThatUsesNavNextDirective {}
```

It's a misconception I think some people have that components/directives only need to be imported once into the app module, and all the other modules get to use it. That's not the case

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ ModuleWithComponentThatUsesNavNextDirective ],
  declarations: [ NavNextDirective ] 
})
class AppModule {}
```

Here, `ModuleWithComponentThatUsesNavNextDirective` can't see the `NavNextDirective` declared in the `AppModule`. It either needs to declare the directive itself, or `imports` a module that `exports` the directive. But do note that a component can be declared only once by any module. So if the component is to be used by many modules, then you should either create a module specifically for that component, or create a shared module that holds a bunch of reusable components.